# What adjective do you use to describe a curve that's very curved?"

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar

Example:

> There weren’t many curves, but those that appeared were so [...] I
>   thought I would fly out of them any time.

I thought of *sharp* and *closed* but they sound weird to me for some reason. What's a more suitable alternative?

Comment: perhaps *tight*?

Comment: I'm going to second *tight*.

Comment: @Nick2253: Assuming you have sufficient reputation points to *upvote* Hellion's comment, you should just do that. I would expect the site mods to delete your comment (and my own here! :) in due course as "irrelevant noise".

Comment: By the way, there is nothing wrong with a *sharp curve*. But a *closed curve* is like a circle: it has no "ends".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **hairpin curve**, **hairpin turn** or **hairpin corner**:

- a very sharp curve in a road, where the road forms a "U" shape
- A hairpin turn (also hairpin bend, hairpin corner, etc.), named for its resemblance to a hairpin/bobby pin, is a bend in a road with a very acute inner angle, making it necessary for an oncoming vehicle to turn almost 180° to continue on the road. Such turns in ramps and trails may be called switchbacks in American English, by analogy with switchback railways.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpin_turn

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/hairpin-curve

An acute-angled curve:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Types_of_angles

Comment: I think the distinguishing feature of a *hairpin bend* is more that the road *after* the bend is almost completely parallel to the approach (but in the opposite direction). The bend itself may be more or less ***tight***, depending on how long or short the curved section is.

Comment: N.B The wiki mark down editor messed up my posting. The first line should read "Hairpin curve, hairpin turn or hairpin corner:", but I have not been successful at trying to correct/edit that. Sumpin's wrong with edit mode.

Comment: Apparently, [AmE favours **turn**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hairpin+curve%2Chairpin+turn%2Chairpin+corner%2Chairpin+bend&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chairpin%20curve%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chairpin%20turn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chairpin%20corner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chairpin%20bend%3B%2Cc0), but in my experience Brits almost always use **bend**.

Comment: @BlessedGeek, I tried to fix it up for you.  :-)

Comment: There's bug in stackexchange database retrieval.

Answer (score 3):

'Extreme', 'severe', or 'sharp' all seem good to me.